# Setup GIT on Windows?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am planning to setup a GIT repository!

I wan't this repository to be located on a NAS server.
My NAS has two 4TB discs which is set under RAID 1.

How should I do to clone such a GIT repository in IntelliJ? I want the source code to be checked in at Q: and the code that I have cloned should be at C: When I program, I want IntelliJ should be attached to the application code in C:

I want to be able to manage everything up from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Since git supports file system remotes this is pretty easy.

1. setup git (http://www.git-scm.org)
2. got to `Q:/<your future git repo folder>`
3. `git init --bare` (This will be your 'remote')
4. fire up IntelliJ and Select `File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> Git`file
5. URL: <del>`file:///q/<folder from above>`</del>`q:/<folder from above>`; the other options are up to you
6. clone
7. develop ;)

Thanks to @crashmstr for pointing out the efficiency problem with the `file://` schema.

Comment: [this says](https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html) specifying `file://` explicitly is usually a lot slower than without, and typically the slowest option of all of the protocols.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Did not know this. Edited the answer.